# How do I check the response code of multiple websites?

Tags: vb.net

i'm a new in VB and i'm trying to make a program that gets and
displays the HTTP response code of a multiple website.

something like:

```
http response code of target website www.example.com : 200 OK 
http response code of target website www.abc2.com : 405 Method Not Allowed
http response code of target website www.testing2.com : 404 Not Found
http response code of target website www.last23.com : 408 RequestTimeout
```

etc.

I Tried to code it myself but i couldn't , And i also tried to find
online but i didn't found something that works.

i found this code but I think I need a loop to check multiple sites
can you help me with that? how can create loop and check status code
for multiple websites

```
  Public Shared Function GetResponse(uri As String) As HttpStatusCode

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse
    Try
        resp = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Catch ex As WebException
        resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
    End Try

    Return resp.StatusCode
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the GetResponse function you've already got it's quite simple

```
Dim sites as new List(of String)
sites.Add("www.example.com")
sites.Add("www.abc2.com")
sites.Add("www.testing2.com")
sites.Add("www.last23.com")

For Each site As String In sites
    Dim siteResponse as String = GetResponse(site)
    Console.WriteLine("http response code of target website " & site & " " & siteResponse)
Next
```

That's just off the top of my head so might have a couple gaffs in it